# ssh ubuntu to android : No route to host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, android

I am trying to log into my android phone (running sshdroid), using my laptop (ubuntu 12.04). I am on a university sub-network (on wifi), and so is my phone.
I tried the following command:

```
ssh root@my_phone_ip -p 2222
```

But the laptop fires back a

```
ssh: connect to host 172.20.27.169 port 2222: No route to host
```

I cannot even ping to my phone, it gives a destination host unreachable error.
I looked for the route information on my laptop which is

```
root@abadmin-Vostro-3500:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

default         eduspot-berlioz 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0

link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0

172.16.185.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1

172.20.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     2      0        0 wlan0

192.168.248.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
```

To check what packets were going through I have tried a tcpdump -i wlan0, but I could not find any interesting packets. I'm inserting the dump here for further info.

```
root@abadmin-Vostro-3500:~# tcpdump -i wlan0 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
19:45:12.354445 IP6 fe80::1416:f700:ff98:a65 > ff02::1:ff3a:6694: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::51e2:6e29:ff3a:6694, length 32
19:45:12.355303 IP abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.54924 > eduspot-berlioz.crous- grenoble.fr.domain: 44239+ PTR?       4.9.6.6.a.3.f.f.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.0.f.f.ip6.arpa. (90)
19:45:12.364296 IP eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr.domain > abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.54924: 44239 NXDomain 0/0/0 (90)
19:45:12.364742 IP abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.53789 > eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr.domain: 29641+ PTR? 5.6.a.0.8.9.f.f.0.0.7.f.6.1.4.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.e.f.ip6.arpa. (90)
19:45:12.368422 IP eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr.domain > abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.53789: 29641 NXDomain 0/0/0 (90)
19:45:12.368740 IP abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.2590 > eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr.domain: 39336+ PTR? 4.9.6.6.a.3.f.f.9.2.e.6.2.e.1.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.e.f.ip6.arpa. (90)
19:45:12.373988 IP eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr.domain > abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.2590: 39336 NXDomain 0/0/0 (90)
19:45:12.374372 IP abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.5879 > eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr.domain: 3348+ PTR? 254.255.20.172.in-addr.arpa. (45)
19:45:12.389099 IP eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr.domain > abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.5879: 3348* 1/0/0 PTR eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr. (92)
19:45:12.389455 IP abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.30761 > eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr.domain: 14063+ PTR? 186.27.20.172.in-addr.arpa. (44)
19:45:12.393315 IP eduspot-berlioz.crous-grenoble.fr.domain > abadmin-Vostro-3500.local.30761: 14063 NXDomain 0/0/0 (44)
^C  19:45:12.411446 IP 172.20.18.214.netbios-ns > 172.20.255.255.netbios-ns: NBT UDP   PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST

12 packets captured
525 packets received by filter
483 packets dropped by kernel
```

iptables output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination 
ACCEPT 47 -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination 
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination'
```

Please help me log into my phone.. its been frustrating me for 2 days now.
Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Make sure firewall is not blocking your access try `iptables -L -n`

Comment: @Networker, I got the following output, can't infer from it though
`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     47   --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination'

Comment: please add the comment to your question using `edit`

Comment: yes, i do have an ip address asssigned to the interface wlan0,
and yes i can ping to my default gateway

Answer (score 1):

edit your firewall to accept the port 2222:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```

if it doesn't solve the problem, selinux might be the problem so try this:

make it allow port 2222:

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2222
```

also see if the port is open using nmap:

```
nmap -p 2222 172.20.27.169
```

and if you have changed any configuration file ( defining the port 2222) you have to restart sshd:

```
service sshd restart
```

Comment: tried it, does not work,
Also if it helps
I tried
`ufw status`
I received 
`Status: inactive`
So net filtering is off AFAIK

Comment: The host seems down, i am wondering why so..? 

`root@abadmin-Vostro-3500:~# nmap -p 2222 172.20.27.169

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-14 20:43 CEST

Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -PN
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.29 seconds
root@abadmin-Vostro-3500:~# nmap -p 2222 172.20.27.169 -PN

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-14 20:44 CEST
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.28 seconds
`